# Can't get all link in a div

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom, scrape

I'm trying to get all link from this [page](http://it.soccerway.com/national/italy/serie-c1/20152016/girone-c/r31861/). Actually there I almost achieve this result with this code:

```
public function getLinks()
{
    $html = file_get_html("http://it.soccerway.com/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/regular-season/r31554/");

    foreach($html->find("div.block_competition_left_tree-wrapper") as $div)
    {
        foreach ($div->find('a') as $li)
        {
            echo $li->href . "<br>";
        }
    }

}
```

this is the result:

```
/national/italy/serie-a/c13/
/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/
/national/italy/serie-b/c14/
/national/italy/serie-c1/c53/
/national/italy/serie-c2/c358/
/national/italy/serie-d/c659/
/national/italy/coppa-italia/c135/
/national/italy/super-cup/c171/
/national/italy/coppa-italia-serie-c/c684/
/national/italy/campionato-nazionale-primavera/c952/
/national/italy/coppa-italia-primavera/c1070/
/national/italy/super-coppa-primavera/c1171/
/national/italy/dante-berretti/c1092/
/national/italy/serie-a-women/c293/
/national/italy/serie-a2/c457/
/national/italy/coppa-italia-women/c852/
/national/italy/super-cup-women/c851/
/national/italy/club-friendlies/
```

the problem is that I need to scrape only the link in the list `<li>`, how you can see in the `html` there is different classes `expanded | odd | even`. Essentially I don't want get the link of the element displayed as `Serie A - Serie B, etc...` but the link inside it. In particular something like this should be the result:

```
/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/
/national/italy/serie-b/20152016/regular-season/r31798/
/national/italy/serie-c1/20152016/girone-c/r31861/
```

now if you see in the first result above there is only `/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/` correct in my final example, this is 'cause in the html page the `Serie A` item have the class `expanded` and the code see the link. How can I fix my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope, I have understood you as well. You need to get all links as you did, then open every link to get all links of the class.

An example:

```
public function getLinks()
{
    $html = file_get_html("http://it.soccerway.com/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/regular-season/r31554/");

    foreach($html->find("div.block_competition_left_tree-wrapper") as $div)
    {

        //get all links
        foreach ($div->find('a') as $li)
        {
            $openLink = file_get_html("http://it.soccerway.com/".$li->href);

            foreach($openLink->find("div.block_competition_left_tree-wrapper") as $divOfNewLink){

                foreach ($divOfNewLink->find('li') as $liOfNewDiv){

                        if (preg_match("/expanded/i", $liOfNewDiv->class)) {

                            foreach ($liOfNewDiv->find('a') as $link)
                            {
                                echo $link->href . "<br>";
                            }

                        }else{
                             // do nothing
                            }


                }
            }

        }


  }
}
```

Comment: you have tested your code? For me doesn't work, the third foreach `foreach($openLink->find("div.block_competition_left_tree-wrapper")` find correctly the link but the class isn't find `expanded even` and `expanded odd`

Comment: @Dillinger sorry for that!. I have edited my answer. this time I have tested my code and it works as well

Comment: seems working well. Anyway, just a question: how can I do for get only the expanded links? Example: `/national/italy/serie-a/c13/` must not be displayed, instead only `/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/s11663/` thanks for the help.